# What is the keycode for "Next" in android virtualKeyBoard

Tags: javascript, angular, virtual-keyboard

I am enhancing (in an angular directive) the google places autocomplete input to select the first option if none is selected.

I am using the below code, which works like a charm when using "tab" or "enter" key.

Unfortunatly it is not working on android device (chrome) whith **virtualkeyboard "next" key**...

What could be the KeyCode of this "**next**" key as it is neither "tab" (9) or "enter" (13)

```
selectFirstOnEnterOrTab(input) {
    // prevent submit on enter (13)
    $(input).keydown(function (e) {
      if (e.which === 13 && $('.pac-container:visible').length) {
        return false;
      }
    });

    // store the original event binding function
    const _addEventListener = (input.addEventListener) ? input.addEventListener : input.attachEvent;
    function addEventListenerWrapper(type, listener) {
      // Simulate a 'down arrow' keypress on hitting 'return' when no pac suggestion is selected,
      // and then trigger the original listener.
      if (type === 'keydown') {
        const orig_listener = listener;
        listener = function (event) {
          const suggestion_selected = $('.pac-item-selected').length > 0;
          if ((event.which >= 9 && event.which <= 13) && !suggestion_selected) {
            const simulated_downarrow = $.Event('keydown', {
              keyCode: 40, which: 40
            });
            orig_listener.apply(input, [simulated_downarrow]);
          }
          orig_listener.apply(input, [event]);
        };
      }
      _addEventListener.apply(input, [type, listener]); // add the modified listener
    }
    if (input.addEventListener) {
      input.addEventListener = addEventListenerWrapper;
    } else if (input.attachEvent) {
      input.attachEvent = addEventListenerWrapper;
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**

Following Pitto suggestion, I have logged which and keycode on my android device, and for all the key I press, I receive 229, which apparently is a normal behaviour for android.
Any ideas on how I can update my code for it to work on Android device too...

**EDIT2**

On android, on "next" pressed, there is no **keydown** event fired

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set a minimal page with this code and see if it prints the right value?

```
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
   console.log(event.key);
   console.log(event.code);
});
```

Or, even easier, you can get keycodes using this website:
https://keycode.info

The tab key data for my Samsung S10e, as returned by https://keycode.info:

```
event.key = Unidentified
event.location = 0
event.which = 229
event.code =
```

Comment: Well thanks for your answer, normally I think of those things but why not for this problem :O :).
Anyway, I have logged which and keycode and for all the key i press (even "a", "b", "enter", ...) I have 229 for both ...

Comment: Apparently it is a "normal" behaviour for android, but how can I get the "enter" or "tab" pressed then...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already, the value for `e.which` / `e.keyCode` is going to be `229` and `e.key` is going to be `'Unidentified'`. You can check that using https://keyjs.dev, where you will also find an explanation about virtual/mobile keyboards:

> When using virtual/mobile keyboards, formally know as IME (Input-Method Editor), the W3C standard states that a KeyboardEvent's e.keyCode should be 229 and e.key should be "Unidentified".

The best option on mobile is probably just adding an expand/down arrow to the dropdown and let users open it manually if they want to.