# What is the keyCode from Android's Next button? (the one that sometimes replaces Enter)

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Found [similar threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081977/what-is-the-keycode-for-next-in-android-virtualkeyboard), but nothing seems to work for me.

I have a simple text input in my Vue app that, needs to be blurred once the user clicks `Enter` of whateve the "Return" button is on their keyboard. This is all fine and well on Desktop and iOS, however on Android the `Enter` button changes to `Next` and will not follow the behavior I set for it.

I've tried a bunch of different keycodes which I've found in different thread answers and so far, none of them match the Next button on Android.

This is what my code looks like:

```js
<v-text-field
  label="My Input"
  class="input-field"
  v-model="myInput"
  @keydown="preventUnwantedEnterDefaultBehavior"
/>
...

private preventUnwantedEnterDefaultBehavior = (evt) => {
// none of these work for next
    if (evt.keyCode === 13 || evt.keyCode === 261 || evt.keyCode === 229 || evt.key === 'Unidentified') {
            evt.target.blur();
        }
}
```

Take note that the `Next` buttons default behaviour is to skip to the next input. I do not want this to happen. I want simple blur of the current input, regardless of what the `Enter` button is labelled as.

Alternatively, if this is really a near impossible task, how can I force the Android's `Next` button to just be your good ol' `Enter` button of code 13 as it on all the other platforms?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using keycode 66? As described in the android documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_ENTER

If that doesn't work you could try to handle the @keyup event for the same codes.

Comment: No good unfortunately. It completely ignores the if check event with your suggestions and `evt.preventDefault()`.